# I can't figure out discord.js v13 buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

I just can't figure out how to send a button interaction with a message in Discord.js v13 in v12 you just use discord-buttons but here it's built-in somehow and I can't quite get it.

Comment: Please show what you tried already including any errors/problems. If you have a problem setting it up, see the link from the answer on this question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('primary')
                    .setLabel('Primary')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
            );

        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', components: [row] });
    }
});
```

For external redirect button, you should use .setLabel('LINK') instead of .setLabel('Primary') then remove .setCustomId('primary'). Add .setURL('URL')

[For more click here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons)

Answer (score -1):

Discord.js has a great documentation and you can find more about buttons in [Buttons Section](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html).
It is well documented and there are some good examples too.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.